# Blazor Webassembly Dynamic Script in Head

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted solution that I am using for a recipe blog.  Google has a Recipe Schema that Id like to use which includes placing a Json object within a  tag in the head.  This JSON is a representation of the recipe so it would be generated in the OnInit when the recipe is fetched from the DB and would have to be placed within that script tag.

How can you do this?

Update:  The issue I have is that prerendering is not supported with an app using authentication.

Comment: Are you prerendering your Blazor? If not, you would have to enable that for Google to be able to see those kind of things.

Comment: I do but i do not think its working correctly.  I try and populate the Title and Description in the head but google analytics shows blank pages in the reporting

Comment: You need to make sure they get rendered into the component before OnAfterRender. If you are doing some data loading from your database you probably need to do it inside OnInitialized. You can check what gets delivered on the initial render with CTRL + U for page source.

Comment: Thanks Axekan.  Looks like the prerendering is not working as CTRL + U is showing the content from index.html in the client project